# MYSQL: Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, key, constraints

basically I have an issue with creating a joined table and don't know how to fix it. I created cInfo first, then mInfo, then eInfo which all worked but then when trying to create cRented it gave me the error: Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint. Any help?
Here is the code:

```
 CREATE TABLE cInfo (
cid int(4) DEFAULT '0',
fname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
sname varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
age int(4) DEFAULT '0',
gender enum('M', 'F') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'M', 
telno int(10) DEFAULT '0',
email varchar(20) NOT NULL,
addr varchar(50) NOT NULL,
cowed int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (cid, cowed)
);

INSERT INTO cInfo VALUES(1,'Smith', 'John', 20, 'M', 0891234567, 
'smith.john@gmail.com', '1 Bishopstown Road, Cork', 10); 


CREATE TABLE mInfo (
mid INT NOT NULL,
title varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
director varchar(100) NOT NULL,
relyear int(4) NOT NULL,
genre enum('Thriller','Horror','Documentary','Comedy','Drama') NOT NULL 
DEFAULT ‘Drama’, 
PRIMARY KEY (mid)
);

INSERT INTO mInfo VALUES(1,'Justice League', 'Zack Snyder', 2017, 'Comedy'); 


CREATE TABLE eInfo (
eid int(4) DEFAULT '0',
ppsn varchar(10) NOT NULL,
fname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
sname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
gender enum(‘M’, ‘F’) NOT NULL DEFAULT ‘M’,  
telno int(10) DEFAULT '0',
email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
addr varchar(200) NOT NULL,
mid INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (mid),

CONSTRAINT eInfo_ref1 FOREIGN KEY (mid) REFERENCES mInfo (mid) 
); 

INSERT INTO eInfo VALUES(1, '1234567A', 'Moyes', 'Richard', 'M', 0871234567, 
'moyes.richard@gmail.com', '1 CIT Road, Cork', 1 );


CREATE TABLE cRented (
cid int(4) DEFAULT '0',
mid INT NOT NULL,
dor Date NOT NULL,
cowed int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
PRIMARY KEY (cid, mid, cowed),

CONSTRAINT cRented_ref1 FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES cInfo (cid),
CONSTRAINT cRented_ref2 FOREIGN KEY (mid) REFERENCES mInfo (mid),
CONSTRAINT cRented_ref3 FOREIGN KEY (cowed) REFERENCES cInfo (cowed) 
);

INSERT INTO cRented VALUES(1, 1, 2017-11-23, 10 );
```

Comment: The FK's must match the PK's. The cInfo has PK (cid, cowed), but the FK references only cid.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't have a foreign key that 's *also* a primary key in the same table. In `eInfo`, you should make `eid` the primary key, not `mid`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge, can be done. (But not very common.)

Comment: @jarlh Where? cRented in ref1 references the cid and ref3 references the cowed.

Comment: A FK must reference a complete PK.

Answer (score 0):

In the following:

```
CONSTRAINT cRented_ref1 FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES cInfo (cid),
CONSTRAINT cRented_ref2 FOREIGN KEY (mid) REFERENCES mInfo (mid),
CONSTRAINT cRented_ref3 FOREIGN KEY (cowed) REFERENCES cInfo (cowed)
```

remove `CONSTRAINT cRented_ref3` in favor of composite foreign key `cRented_ref1`:

```
CONSTRAINT cRented_ref1 FOREIGN KEY (cid, cowed) REFERENCES cInfo (cid, cowed),
CONSTRAINT cRented_ref2 FOREIGN KEY (mid) REFERENCES mInfo (mid)
```

That way `cRented_ref1` matches the composite primary key on `cInfo`.

Table eInfo is not likely an issue in this case though making the primary key and foreign key constraints the same column implies a 1:1 relationship between the data in eInfo and mInfo.